# Format date dd/mm/yyyy in java

Tags: java, date

I have a problem to format the returned date.

The date is returned is : 2011-04-05
I want to return 05/04/2011
Could you help me please ?

```
private Date getMaxDate() {

        DbCall st = new DbCall("?:=Package_Name.GET_DATE", this.getDBTransaction());
        st.addRet("ret", Types.DATE);
        st.addIn(getCarId());
        st.execute();
        java.util.Date jd = (java.util.Date)st.getObj("ret");

        if (jd == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return new oracle.jbo.domain.Date(new java.sql.Timestamp(jd.getTime()));
    }
```

Comment: If you want to return something "formatted", you need to return a `String`; a `Date` has no "format".

Comment: what is this `05/04/2011-04-05`, use `SimpleDatFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object can be converted to any String format using a SimpleDateFormat see the following example which will build a String representation of the date in the format dd/MM/yyyy which seems to be the format you are looking for.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String DateToStr = format.format(curDate);
```